# c++ toDouble() converts string to 0

Tags: c++, qt

So the idea is that for every number pressed the number is pushed onto a `nums` deque. Then when the decimal button is pressed, it pushes all the `nums` onto a new deque called `specialDecimal` and push a "." after these numbers. Also sets a boolean called `decimalClicked` to be true. So now I have numbers before decimal + a decimal. Then when an operator is pressed, it pushes the numbers in `nums` which are the numbers after the decimal into `specialDecimal`. So then when equals button is pressed I do a special evaluation for `decimalClicked`:

```
//special case if decimal is pressed
double actualVal = 0;
QString s = "";
bool ok; //for toDouble

if(decimalClicked){
    while(!(specialDecimal.empty())){
        QString s = specialDecimal.front();
        cerr << s.toStdString();
        s.append(s);
        specialDecimal.pop_front();
    }
    cerr << endl << "should be whole string number: " << s.toStdString();
    actualVal = s.toDouble(&ok);
    cerr << endl << "should be value: " << actualVal;
    nums.push_front(actualVal);
}`
```

Output for cerr are:

```
8.1
should be whole string number: 
should be value: 0
```

The cerr print statement inside the while loop shows that it is parsing the decimal number correctly. The cerr statement right under the while loop doesn't print out the entire string. Also the result displayed is basically 0 + `the second number` if I do the operator `+`. I can show more code if need be.

Comment: You seem to expect that, by some dark magic, the two occurrences of `s` in `s.append(s)` refer to two different objects. Give different names to different variables.

Comment: Wow, that did the trick. I thought that would just append its current QString to itself?? But thanks!!

Comment: Yes, it does append the string declared inside the loop to itself; immediately after, at the loop's closing brace, that string is destroyed. The string declared outside of the loop - the one you call `toStdString` on - remains empty. Your whole loop is equivalent to `specialDecimal.clear()`; it achieves nothing else.

Comment: Oh! Totally went over my head. Haha, probably means I need a break. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is one of variable scope.

```
//special case if decimal is pressed
double actualVal = 0;
QString s = ""; // <----------------------- s variable declared in outer scope
bool ok; //for toDouble

if(decimalClicked){
    while(!(specialDecimal.empty())){
        QString s = specialDecimal.front(); // <-- s variable declared in
                                            //     while loop scope which
                                            //     hides the s variable
                                            //     in the outer scope
        cerr << s.toStdString();
        s.append(s);
        specialDecimal.pop_front();
    } // <---------------------------------- second s variable goes out 
      //                                     of scope         
    cerr << endl << "should be whole string number: " << s.toStdString();
    actualVal = s.toDouble(&ok);
    nums.push_front(actualVal);
}
```

Try this instead:

```
//special case if decimal is pressed
double actualVal = 0;
QString s = "";
bool ok; //for toDouble

if(decimalClicked){
    while(!(specialDecimal.empty())){
        QString a = specialDecimal.front();  // note variable renamed to avoid
                                             // collision
        cerr << s.toStdString();
        s.append(a);
        specialDecimal.pop_front();
    }
    cerr << endl << "should be whole string number: " << s.toStdString();
    actualVal = s.toDouble(&ok);
    nums.push_front(actualVal);
}
```